# BigQuery COUNT(*) ... WHERE NOT (...) returns confusing results

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with `device` column which could be 'P', 'T' or NULL, but the condition like `device NOT IN('P', 'T')` seems to miss the rows with NULL. Can be demonstrated with following queries

```
$ bq query 'SELECT count(*) FROM t'
+----------+
|   f0_    |
+----------+
| 29542063 |
+----------+
$ bq query "SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE device = 'P' OR device = 'T'"
+---------+
|   f0_   |
+---------+
| 8268436 |
+---------+
$ bq query "SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE NOT (device = 'P' OR device = 'T')"
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|   0 |
+-----+
$ bq query "SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE device IS NULL"
+----------+
|   f0_    |
+----------+
| 21273627 |
+----------+
```

Why the query with `WHERE NOT` returns `0` while `IS NULL` one returns correct result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Why the query with WHERE NOT returns 0 while IS NULL one returns correct result?"

Because

```
SELECT null != 'anything'
```

returns 'null', not 'false'.